# Issue in Elastic Search Sum Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to the example from the elastic search site with my own parameters, but it is not working.

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "activity_date": {
            "from": "2013-11-01",
            "to": "2014-11-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "net_ordered_units": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "net_ordered_units"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error I get:

```
{
  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[YoGKlejVTC6jhg_OgPWXyTg][test][0]: SearchParseException[[test][0]: query[ConstantScore(cache(activity_date:[1383264000000 TO 1414886399999]))],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\": {\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}},\"filter\":{\"range\":{\"activity_date\":{\"from\":\"2013-11-01\",\"to\":\"2014-11-01\"}}}}},\"aggs\":{\"net_ordered_units\":{\"sum\": {\"field\":\"net_ordered_units\"}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[test][0]: query[ConstantScore(cache(activity_date:[1383264000000 TO 1414886399999]))],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [aggs]]]; }]", 
  "status": 400
}
```

What is shard failure here? And it says no parser for aggs, what should I do here?
Basically, I need to perform operations like sum and then find the max out of it.
How should I modify the above code to get that?

Comment: Are you using any plugin to administrate your cluster?

Comment: @eliasah  Yes, internal wrapper plugin.

Comment: Are you using Elasticsearch 1.0.0 or newer?

Comment: @AlexBrasetvik ES 1.0.0, does that make a difference ?

Comment: That search should work on anything >= 1.0.0, and give an error like the one you have there on older versions as aggregations were introduced in 1.0.0.

Comment: You might have a shard that have fallen down. That's why I asked you about the administrator plugin. You need something like the elasticsearch head plugin so you can visualize your cluster : health, state, meta etc.

Comment: @AlexBrasetvik Is there no other way to get sum other than aggregations ?

Comment: The key here is the `No parser for element [aggs]]` part of the error message. Try running `curl localhost:9200/_search -d '{"bogus_field_that_is_not_valid_in_a_search_object": {}}'` and you'll still get a shard failure wrapping a parse failure. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  your plugin (which you use to perform the CURL based elastic-search queries) is not able to parse the "aggs" tag. I use the Marvel Sense plugin (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/marvel/current/) specifically for ES queries and your query works fine ! I did a test on  Postman ( a RESTful Chrome Plugin) and guess what, nothing wrong with your query...  So try switching your plugin and see if that helps.

Updated:
To answer the second part of your question,

```
curl -s -XPOST  your_ES_server/ES_index/url_to_query -d    
'{"query": 
  {"bool": 
   { 
   "must": [{ 
 "wildcard" : { "item_id" : "*" }
          }]
  }
 },
 "facets" : {
  "facet_result":
    {"terms":{
      "fields":["item_count"]
    }}

}
```

Gotcha, Actually the above query doesn't fetch you the maximum count of a specific field key but lists you all the field keys sorted by their count in descending order(by default). So naturally the top most term should be what you are looking for. The response to the above query looks as follows.

```
 "facets": {
  "facet_result": {
     "_type": "terms",
     "missing": 0,
     "total": 35,
     "other": 0,
     "terms": [
        {
           "term": 0,
           "count": 34
        },
        {
           "term": 2,
           "count": 1
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

This might not be a clean solution but can help you retrieve the max(sum) of a key. For more info on ordering, refer http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/search-facets-terms-facet.html#_ordering

Comment: Thanks for that info, I will try changing the plugin and look into it. Coming to 2nd part, I think your query does find sum and max of a field whereas I want to find sum first then max among the sum values. Something like max(sum) in SQL query.

Comment: Just for my understanding to confirm, facets acts as group by (in SQL) to group all similar terms and returns count of it. By using ordering, we sort in descending order of count and pop the first element to get the maximum out of it. Am I right ?

Comment: @thirstylad : Spot on !